# BindingList updates object changes but ignores new or deleted objects

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datasource, bindinglist

I'm working on a Winforms project using C#.  The issue is that the BindingList updates object changes but my DataGrid and Combox Box ignores new or deleted objects that are added or removed from the BindingList, unless I re-assign the BindingList to the datasource.

I initialise and load the data to the BindingList when the application starts.

```
namespace PriceComparer
{
    static class Program
    {
        public static BindingList<Models.Hotel> Hotels;

        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
           Application.EnableVisualStyles();
           Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
           Hotels = new BindingList<Models.Hotel>(Models.Hotel.LoadHotels());                

           Application.Run(new Dashboard());            
       }
    }
}
```

This is my object

```
namespace PriceComparer.Models
{
    public class Hotel
    {
        public string HotelCode { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The databound DataGrid, TextBox and ComboBoxes all observe the changes, so when I change the property value of a object in the text boxes, I can see them being updated in the DataGrid.

[image]

I assign the BindingList like

```
bindingSource_FindHotel.DataSource = 
    Program.Hotels.Where(r => r.Name.ToLower().Contains(txtHotelName.Text.ToLower()));
```

However, when I try to remove a item from the BindingList I use the following code, the object is removed from the BindingList, but the DataGrid is not updated...

```
    private void dataGridFindHotel_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == btnDelete.Index)
        {
            Models.Hotel hotel = (Models.Hotel)bindingSource_FindHotel.Current;

            if(hotel != null)
            {                    
                Program.Hotels.Remove(hotel);
                Models.Hotel.SaveHotels(Program.Hotels);                    
            }
        }
    }
```

Also, when I add a item to the BindingList `Program.Hotels`, the DataGrid and Combobox don't update, unless I refresh or re-assign the DataSource.

The Combobox is assigned the BindingList like this

```
bindingSource_Hotel.DataSource = Program.Hotels.OrderBy(r => r.Name);

cmbHotel.DisplayMember = "Name";
cmbHotel.ValueMember = "Name";
```

The bindingSource_Hotel is the DataSource for the Combobox.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `bindingSource_FindHotel.DataSource =  Program.Hotels.Where(...)`. You're not assigning the `BindingList`, you assigning an `IEnumerable<class>`. Use the DataSource.DefaultView to filter the data, if needed.

Comment: I tried adding `(dataGridFindHotel.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("FindHotel_Name LIKE '%{0}%'", txtHotelName.Text.ToLower());`  but get `Object not set to a instance of a object`

Comment: Apply the filter to the BindingSource (`bindingSource_Hotel`).

Comment: I'm not sure why, but I get the same `Object not set to a instance of a object` when applying to `bindingSource_Hotel`  as well

Comment: `DataView view = (bindingSource_FindHotel.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView; view.RowFilter = $"FindHotel_Name LIKE '%{txtHotelName.Text.ToLower()}%'"; dataGridFindHotel.DataSource = view;`. Of course, that BindingSource.DataSource needs to be already assigned (using a DataTable or some other valid source).

Comment: When you say '(using a DataTable or some other valid source)' I was assigning as `bindingSource_FindHotel.DataSource = Program.Hotels;` with Program.Hotels being a `BindingList`

Comment: Nope. Of course a BindingList doesn't have a DefaultView you can filter. That's why I was (possibly in a too subtle manner :) suggesting to use a DataTable instead. It'ld make, IMO, everything much easier to handle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190921/discussion-between-neildt-and-jimi).